# How to set up bootstrap installation on node.js project via npm installation

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, npm, bootstrap-4

[image]I am working on a simple project for learning node.js and I tried installing bootstrap via npm. The bootstrap.css seems to be working but the output on the page is poor, also downloaded Jquery and tether, but the bootstrap.js and the jquery.js files are not loading when I check the network section of the web page.

I have set the directories as static using express.static but the files are still not loading.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/tether/dist/js'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/jquery/dist'));


    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/tether.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
<%- include('includes/header') %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light navbar-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PassportApp</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Members Area</h1>
    <p> Welcome to the members area.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->

<%- include('includes/footer') %>
```

Comment: can you check out the relative path to your `JS` files?

Comment: They are in my node_modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's NO `tether.js` in Bootstrap 4 (anymore).

Which means you are trying to load an *outdated* version of Bootstrap.

Secondly, the order in which you load JS files matters. In your case, you are loading `tether.js` after `bootstrap.min.js` which is definitely NOT the right way to do it.

Here's a handy HTML template for you with all the right files and in the correct order (re-install Bootstrap and make sure your installation outputs that kind of files):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use a cdn because of network issues. I am using bootstrap 4. I also npm installed tether and jquery.

Comment: You don't need to use CDN. That template just shows in which order the files must be loaded (which you aren't doing). And also shows that you aren't actually using the release version of Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized the syntax i was using with the bootstrap was the real problem. I was using bootstrap 4 alpha syntax on the bootstrap 4.0.0

Comment: That's right. The alpha version is very old and outdated. Lots of things have changed since that version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom script like additionalScript.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New App</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favico.ico" />
        <script src="assets/js/additionalScript.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body class="skin-light-blue" style="display:none">

    </body>
</html>
```

So no need to an extra '/' which you have added before `js`.